# Export to excel or csv

Tags: php, jquery, excel, csv, export

I'm working on website where I need to make a excel file or at least a csv file that opens in excel.
I tried alot of things. I searched for solutions on google, stackoverflow, etc. But everything I find seems not to work for me. I tried jQuery solutions and I tried PHP solutions.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/

When I use this fiddle to make a csv the output is:

[image: Example of the csv ouput]

I want the output to be in seperate colums, not in one.

Here is also a PHP solution I tried:

```
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.xls");

    echo "<html>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Henk</td>";
    echo "<td>Henk2</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>bob</td>";
    echo "<td>bob2</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
```

This outputs:

[image: example of php output]

Here the output is in the right columns and rows. But somehow I can't get gridlines.

This are just 2 examples of the tons I tried. Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/) example you've provided - change `colDelim = '","'` to `colDelim = '";"'` since it needs the comma separated value `;` to make the string fall in different cells.

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KPEGU/2386/)

Answer (score 0):

I can see where your going with thinking about using tables to do the formatting but CSV's are comma seperated.

The best way I've found is to use arrays like so:

```
// setup array. Note null values to create empty cells
$list = array( 
    array('First row', NULL, 'some_data', NULL),
    array('Second row', 'some data', NULL, 'some data'),
); 

// set header types
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="most_popular-'.$_POST['start_date'].'-'.$_POST['end_date'].'.csv"');

// tell php to open the page as an output (download)
$outstream = fopen("php://output",'w');

// loop through and put each array row into the csv, comma seperated.
foreach( $list as $row )  
{  
    fputcsv($outstream, $row, ',');  
}  

exit;
```

Just remember that each row in the array needs the exact same as the others otherwise the loop to generate the csv will get very confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this**




 <?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
include("dbConnect.inc.php");
//$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP
    $select_table=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `key_cat`");
    $setExcelName="Keyword_reports";
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$setExcelName.'.csv');
/*
$setExcelName="Keywords";
 header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$setExcelName."_Reoprt.xls");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
*/
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);
if($rows)
{
getcsv(array_keys($rows));
}
while($rows)
{
getcsv($rows);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);
}
// get total number of fields present in the database
function getcsv($no_of_field_names)
{
$separate = '';
// do the action for all field names as field name
foreach ($no_of_field_names as $field_name)
{
if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field_name))
{
$field_name = '' . str_replace('', $field_name) . '';
}
echo $separate . $field_name;

//sepearte with the comma
$separate = ',';
}

//make new row and line
echo "\r\n";

}


?>
```